# Image header wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, header, integration

I try to add image in my wordpress header on the left  and right ( like the img) but i don't know how I can do this.
If someone have an idea.

I have the robot and the girl in png

Thanks for help
[image header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aEtK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a development question without what you have tried...
If you don't know how to do it, **don't play around with the code**...
In short, you have to find where your menu is fired, mostly in `header.php` by :

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        .
        .
        .
    )
);
```

and insert your desired images before and after.

Hope this will get you on track.